# How can I write specific CSS for a specific page in word press?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to make differently stylized pages by wordpress.

I tried the **Simple Custom CSS** plugin. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Option1:** WordPress automatically adds a unique class to the `<body>` tag of each page, so you can target that class in your CSS. You can use the `body_class()` function to output the class in your theme's HTML, then use that class to target the specific page in your CSS.

**Option2:** If you're using a custom page template, WordPress will also add a class to the `<body>` tag that corresponds to the **template name**. You can use that class to target the specific page in your CSS.

**Option3:** WordPress also adds a class to the `<body>` tag that corresponds to the **page ID**. You can use that class to target the specific page in your CSS.

Comment: Can I do it by any plugin?